# angular 12 webworker 404

Tags: angular, web-worker

I have updated my project from Angular 11 to Angular 12 and got everything working except of my webworkers. When I do a build, the worker.ts files are not copied to the output directory and when loading in ng serve, I get a 404 for the worker files.

In angular.json under "build" I have this:

```
  "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json"
```

and my tsconfig.worker.json contains this:

```
 {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/worker",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```

I didn´t change anything here....how can i trace why it doesn´t include the worker.ts files?

Comment: With ng serve you always will get 404, because ng serve doest work with web-workers

Comment: Hmm...everything worked with ng serve before I migrated to Angular 12. And as I said, even when I do a ng build, the worker.ts files are not copied to the dist directory.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I found the issue:
I used to create the worker like so (and it worked for angular 11):

```
new Worker('/src/app/shared/workers/get-all-files.worker.ts',
        { name: 'getEntityMetricsLeg', type: 'module' })
```

After I changed to the below, everything worked again:

```
new Worker(new URL('/src/app/shared/workers/get-all-files.worker.ts', import.meta.url),
        { name: 'getEntityMetricsLeg', type: 'module' })
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when I forgot to re-run yarn start to recompile my app